# NEXTjs input file and FormData for sending to backend nodejs

Tags: node.js, next.js, multipartform-data

I'm working on app with NextJs. I want to send a pdf file from my nextjs app to my backend nodejs. I known my node js api route works 'cause I use it on an other app (only React). On this app, I use new FormData(), and append file and post it to my backend.
With nextjs, I can't add my file to FormData... I show you the code:

```
"use client"

import { SidebarContext } from "@/app/_context/SidebarContext"
import { Button, Input } from "@material-tailwind/react"
import axios from "axios"
import { ChangeEvent, useContext, useRef, useState } from "react"
import FormData from "form-data"

export const ProfileWrapper = () => {
    const [curriculumVitae, setCurriculumVitae] = useState<any>()
    const { isOpen, setIsOpen } = useContext(SidebarContext)
    const fd = new FormData()
    const fileInput = useRef<any>()
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        try {
            fd.append("test", "test1")
            console.log(curriculumVitae) // return a File
            console.log(fd) // return FormData{} 
            // axios.post(
            //     `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/candidate/cv/upload`,
            //     curriculumVitae,
            //     {
            //         headers: {
            //             "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            //         },
            //     }
            // )
            console.log("File uploaded successfully!")
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    const handleSelectedFile = (e: any) => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            const selectedFile = fileInput.current.files[0]
            const cv = e.target.files[0]
            fd.append("cv", curriculumVitae)
            setCurriculumVitae(cv)
            console.log(curriculumVitae)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div
            className={`${
                isOpen ? "ms-[310px]" : "ms-[130px]"
            } w-full transition`}
        >
            <input
                type="file"
                name="cv"
                placeholder="Chargez votre CV"
                accept="application/pdf"
                onChange={handleSelectedFile}
                ref={fileInput}
            />
            <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Envoyer</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So as I wrote it by comments, console.log(fd) returns FormData{}.
I test with useRef, I test with all...

Thanks for your time.